# Where would I download Twitter Bootstrap templates?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I noticed that Twitter provides examples like this: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/carousel.html

However, I don't see any download link. Is there a way for me to download the CSS and Javascript of that template?

Comment: [Here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/)?

Comment: You could just hit Ctrl + U (view the page source) on the example. You'd be able to see the links to the CSS and JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use Bootstrap 3.2 as 2.3.2 is deprecated.

[download Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download)

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/ <- this is the updated example with Bootstrap 3.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active left">
      <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Example headline.</h1>
          <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item next left">
      <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAGZmZgAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAFVVVQAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a little nitpicky thing; Bootstrap is up to v3.2.0, not just v3.0.

Comment: That's why I said 3.0+ :) I edited so it's more specific. The carousel code for 3.0 is still valid though.

Comment: You're correct; it's still valid (and I may have been a little excited over 3.2's release today)